# What is the constant WP_USE_THEMES for?

Tags: theme-development

Regarding the `WP_USE_THEMES` constant, the [Codex states](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Using_The_Loop):

> If you are using The Loop inside your
>   own design (and your own design is not
>   a template), set WP_USE_THEMES to
>   false.

But what is the actual effect on WordPress from `WP_USE_THEMES` being set to true or false? I would like to know how it's used by WP.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is only used in [`template-loader.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/template-loader.php), to determine whether it should load a theme file or not. The normal "boot sequence" of WordPress (started in [`wp-blog-header.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-blog-header.php)) loads the plugins, parses the URL, executes a post query based on the URL, and calls the theme. This main post query is typically used in "The Loop". So if you want all the advantages of URL parsing but not display it using the site theme, you can set `WP_USE_THEMES` to `false` and it will not execute that final step.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I'll study those files further to get it fully.

Comment: Just to clarify, the active theme's `functions.php` file will still be loaded. It is only the theme template(s) that aren't loaded.

Comment: What would be a practical example of a situation where this is used? Why would someone want to prevent the theme from loading?

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner: Maybe you implemented a backend action, that should not return a full HTML response. Similar to how cron is implemented, or an API that returns the data in another format?

Comment: Just to add to the answer in the comments: presumably, this would come into play if WordPress was used headlessly (e.g., via wp-cli).

Answer (score 1):

Based on this line in The Loop documentation:
 `<?php define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); get_header(); ?>`
 I would assume that the purpose of `WP_USE_THEMES` in this example is to run action handlers registered to the `get_header` hook, but not actually execute the header template file.