# how to make wordpress not to look for themes

Tags: functions

For a particular project, I'm currently using only wp's admin and core functions/sugars, so no themes. Still, I'm forced to choose a theme.

I would like a couple of things:

1. move theme's functions.php (that currently contains only custom code by me) in /wp-contents, outside the themes and make WP still load it
2. force WP not to look for themes, so I can succefully delete the themes folder without getting an error in wp-admin

Is this possible? What's the best way (without hacking the core)?

Point 2 is less crucial, since I can always hide the admin's themes button. Point 1 is important.

For point 1, maybe I could load functions at the end of wp-config.php, or maybe (still in wp-config) I could hook at 'init' or 'setup_theme'. Or maybe something else.. I'd like to know the best practice here.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a reasons why you not just put your code from the `functions.php` into [Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins) or [Must Use Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins), it isn't that hard to do and is, in my mind preferable, to connecting this task somehow to the `wp-config.php`.

Besides that, if you don't absolutely have to remove the backend/admin themes functionality itself, just remove, unset and/or make it inaccessible from the backend/admin area. Seems more practical to me, probably not knowing all the determining factors of course.

Edit: this is complementary to what @ravs suggested

Comment: I didn't know about 'must use plugins', it's interesting. I'll take a deeper look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Setting WP_USE_THEME to false inside of index.php in wordpress directory, can save some execution time by skipping the theme loading process.

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
```

This [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/12923/63226) explains the process more.

Note:: But I think using the [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) may be a better route now a days.