# Disable Theme API / Front end (for API only environment)

Tags: themes, theme-options, api

I can't remember in which talk I saw this but there is a codex function to disable the front end altogether.

I am not talking about the blank theme as mentioned here:
[Disable front end to use as CMS only?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17969/disable-front-end-to-use-as-cms-only)

I am talking about shutting down the themes API altogether.

Answer (score 2):

There is the constant [`WP_USE_THEMES`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.1/src/wp-includes/template-loader.php) which when set to `false` in `wp-config.php` disables the theme system on the backend, [though it does not completely disable the theme subsystem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/12919/21376). I think that is a close as you can get. I am not 100% sure of that though.

Comment: I'll give this q a day to marinate but this looks like the answer to me! Thanks!